# Delete pointer to 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a pointer to a 2d array of Robot class

```
Robot ***rob;
```

And below is my code for the constructor. The constructor works fine, but now I am trying to build a destructor to delete this pointer and it keeps on crashing the program!

My question is, how can I delete the pointer to the 2d array of robots?

```
RobotsWorld::RobotsWorld(int x , int y)
{
    X=x;Y=y; // returns the limitation of the matrix 
    rob = new Robot**[x];
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        rob[i] = new Robot*[y];

        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            rob[i][j] = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're settings the pointer to null, not deleting it.

Comment: you are doing one of the most dangerous things that you can do with a pointer, setting it to NULL when you are thinking about deleting it; you probably want to adopt the smart pointers and save yourself a lot of troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Code is not tested
for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < y ; ++j)
    {
        delete rob[i][j];
    }
    delete[] rob[i];
}
delete[] rob;
```

By the way, why do you set `rob[i][j] = NULL;` ?

I think it should be : `rob[i][j] = new double;`

Comment: i tried doing that , but the program still crashes , when it enters the delete[] rob[i][j];  while the value is null it is cool , otherwise it crash :(